# Symfony cant login without session.auto_start=1

Tags: php, symfony

I have created an application with a login form.
I have followed these instructions: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

However, if I want to log in via a POST request, the POST does not work.
In the LoginFormAuthenticator the login token is not validated.

```
csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)
```

I discovered that the user gets a session.

```
csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)
```

now returns true

If I set session.auto_start= to 1 in the PHP.ini file session.auto_start= sessions are started.

But Symfony does not recommend session.auto_start=1. How can I solve this problem ?

The solution for my problem:

Result of command `php bin/console debug:config framework session`

Result:

```
enabled: true
storage_id: session.storage.native
handler_id: session.handler.native_file
cookie_httponly: true
cookie_samesite: null
gc_probability: 1
save_path: '%kernel.cache_dir%/sessions'
metadata_update_threshold: 0
```

Use the output in the

> config/packages/framework.yaml

file.

Comment: The csrf protection does need a session to work.  Normally Symfony just handles this unless you maybe did something to disable sessions?  From the command line, run 'bin/console debug:config framework session' and update your question with the results.

Comment: This solution solved my problem thanks.

Comment: Hmmm.  I think what 'fixed' the problem is that the cache was cleared as a result running the command.  debug:config merely shows the current configuration.  Glad you got it working.